Read Polar HRM data over Serial over Bluetooth in C# on Windows
I have an old Polar WearLink Bluetooth HRM from around 2013 that I am trying to revive for a pet project. I can read valid data from the sensor for 30 secs but then the stream stops.
The device was originally sold as compatible with Android phones and predates Polar's similar Bluetooth Smart (LE) HRM sensor, but no current software appears to be natively compatible with mine. I'm trying Windows and Visual Studio because that's what's installed on my laptop. I briefly tried bluetoothctl and rfcomm on Ubuntu and Raspberry Pi OS to get a bit of device info, but my skill set is a bit weak on those two platforms to succeed.
I can pair it with Windows using 0000 as the PIN code, and once paired, two new COM ports appear in the Bluetooth Settings panel: COM3 and COM5.



Port
Direction
Name




COM3
Incoming
Polar iWL


COM5
Outgoing
Polar iWL 'Bluetooth Serial Port'



A minimal C# program net8.0 opens the serial port COM5 and reads the binary data, printing it to the Console as it goes. Every attempt to read from the other port COM3 results in a timeout so I focused my attention on COM5:
using var com = new SerialPort("COM5", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
com.DtrEnable = true;
com.ReadTimeout = 2000;
com.PinChanged += (object sender, SerialPinChangedEventArgs e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay} Pin {e.EventType}");
};
com.Open();
var stopRequested = false;
var input = new byte[32];
while (!stopRequested)
{
    try
    {
        int count;
        if ((count = com.Read(input, 0, input.Length)) > 0)
        {
            Console.Write($"{DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay} Data ");
            for (var b = 0; b < count; b++)
            {
                Console.Write($"{input[b]:X2}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay} Read timeout expired");
    }
}

Now here's the problem: after 30 seconds, the sensor stops sending data, and after a further 20 seconds there's some activity on the pins, but I generally have to set stopRequested = true at this point to break out of the read loop.
13:22:03.8619012 Data FE08F701B1000136
13:22:03.8577468 Pin DsrChanged
13:22:04.4953681 Data FE
13:22:04.4969249 Data 08F702B1000136
13:22:05.2512686 Data FE
13:22:05.2527305 Data 08F703B1000136
13:22:06.7675409 Data FE
13:22:06.7689662 Data 08F704B1000136
13:22:07.4987825 Data FE
13:22:07.5002588 Data 08F705B1000136
13:22:08.8851757 Data FE0A
13:22:08.9155019 Data F506B15402CA02B1
13:22:10.2453147 Data FE
13:22:10.2466293 Data 0AF507B15602A40297
13:22:11.5265342 Data FE
13:22:11.5279903 Data 0AF508B1580288027F
13:22:12.8091522 Data FE
13:22:12.8393198 Data 0AF509B159027C0293
13:22:14.2953905 Data FE
13:22:14.3255601 Data 0AF50AB15802C60308
13:22:15.1305424 Data FE08
13:22:15.1606073 Data F70BB1580342
13:22:16.8153522 Data FE
13:22:16.8167134 Data 0AF50CB1560354033B
13:22:17.6465432 Data FE
13:22:17.6480100 Data 08F70DB1550339
13:22:19.3277329 Data FE
13:22:19.3291894 Data 0AF50EB152034E0346
13:22:20.1590417 Data FE08
13:22:20.1655605 Data F70FB1500337
13:22:21.7452686 Data FE
13:22:21.7466758 Data 0AF500B14F03250317
13:22:23.2530742 Data FE
13:22:23.2548565 Data 0AF501B14F02FF02E1
13:22:23.9853238 Data FE
13:22:24.0055658 Data 08F702B14F02E5
13:22:25.4890527 Data FE
13:22:25.4905051 Data 0AF503B15002E102E9
13:22:26.9952750 Data FE
13:22:26.9967713 Data 0AF504B15002F902EF
13:22:28.5266256 Data FE
13:22:28.5280286 Data 0AF505B15002FB02F9
13:22:29.2828907 Data FE
13:22:29.2843060 Data 08F706B14F02FB
13:22:30.7893006 Data FE
13:22:30.7945983 Data 0AF507B14F02FE02E3
13:22:32.2703884 Data FE
13:22:32.2718069 Data 0AF508B15002E102DE
13:22:32.9829024 Data FE
13:22:32.9936457 Data 08F709B15002DB
13:22:34.3929049 Data FE
13:22:34.3943777 Data 0AF50AB15202BE02B4
13:22:35.7241157 Data FE
13:22:35.7254691 Data 0AF50BB154029C0297
13:22:37.0553895 Data FE
13:22:37.0568060 Data 0AF50CB155029102A1
13:22:38.4866687 Data FE
13:22:38.4930802 Data 0AF50DB15502C002E7
13:22:40.5410014 Read timeout expired
13:22:42.5810109 Read timeout expired
13:22:44.6262821 Read timeout expired
13:22:46.6891852 Read timeout expired
13:22:48.7313436 Read timeout expired
13:22:50.7762505 Read timeout expired
13:22:52.8305981 Read timeout expired
13:22:54.8795041 Read timeout expired
13:22:56.9218766 Read timeout expired
13:22:58.9370365 Read timeout expired
13:22:59.5005538 Pin CtsChanged
13:22:59.5011601 Pin DsrChanged
13:22:59.5024485 Pin CDChanged
13:22:59.5051094 Pin Ring

At 13:22:03.8577468 the DsrHolding property went high, then at 13:22:59.5011601 it returned low. To my untrained eye, this indicates the sensor is no longer ready to send data.
If I run the C# program again immediately after this, it connects and prints another 30 seconds of data, followed by 20 seconds of nothing, then a few pin changes. I can repeat this ad nauseum. Every time pretty much the same result.
I decoded the packet format with the help of:

https://xdaforums.com/t/someone-can-decode-polar-bt-hrm-belts-protocol.614222/ [1]
https://ww.telent.net/2012/5/3/listening_to_a_polar_bluetooth_hrm_in_linux [2]
https://github.com/matejdro/My-Tracks/blob/master/MyTracks/src/com/google/android/apps/mytracks/services/sensors/PolarMessageParser.java [3]




0
1
2
3
4
5
6-7
8-9
10-11




0xFE
Len
Flags
Seq
Flags
BPM
RR1
RR2
RR3



The first four packets from the sensor always indicate that no heart rate was detected, but from the fifth packet a heart rate is detected and one or more R-R values are included in the packet (depending on how fast my heart is beating). While I don't understand the packet fully, I understand enough to make basic use of the heart rate measurement. It also shows that the sensor is 'waking up' for a few seconds before it acquires a heart rate. This indicates to me that the correct approach is NOT to close and reopen COM5 every 30 seconds, but rather that I am doing something wrong.
Link 1 mentions two packets in an "initial connection", however I never receive them, nor can I send them to the sensor. If I send any data to the sensor at all, it stops sending its packets almost immediately. I haven't actually tried all combinations, obviously, but I have tried both:
0a f5 0c d1 4c 03 06 02 fc
0a f5 0a d1 49 03 5e 03 44

and
fe 0a f5 0c d1 4c 03 06 02 fc
fe 0a f5 0a d1 49 03 5e 03 44

where the fe prefix makes it look more like one of the valid packets received, and the 0a even coincidentally matches the 10-octet packet length.
I've tried different handshakes, different bauds, different data bit lengths, different parity, different stop bits, but nothing so far has helped me read more than 30 seconds from the device. I even download Portmon before I realized it wouldn't run on my Windows 10 laptop.
It feels a bit like the sensor expects me to send something periodically to keep the connection alive (CtsHolding is high) otherwise it prioritises saving its battery, but when I send anything, it instead terminates the connection prematurely.
If I could get MyTracks [2] to run then I might be able to see an example of a successful and long-running connection, and I'd know if there were (or weren't) some special bytes that I need to send, or some different set up for the SerialPort that I could match in C#.

What i recommend to try is to connect to your device directly by Bluetooth (without using vCOMs). That may help to locate the problem. You can try RfCommClient demo from Bluetooth Framework or similar example from 32feet.
